# Maya Python Select component

Tags: python, components, selection, maya

I'm currently working on a tool to make clusters from selected edge loops. I was wondering if any of you know how do I get the edge loop from my selection.

Comment: from cmds.ls() ? what do you mean ?

Comment: I need the edge's Ids..
Now Im using:
import re
sel = cmds.ls(sl=True)
ids = [re.findall(r"[\w]+", i)[2] for i in sel]

it's returning a list but not in the order Ive selected the edges. For example, if I select edge 45, 89 and 90, the id list returns 90, 45, 90...
I wonder if is there any flag in ls command that returns me in the selected order, but I cant find it ..

Comment: Yes there is something to trigger the 'ordered selection' but it doesn't work with selecting a whole loop, you have to select edges one by one

Comment: Otherwise there is a command to find the 'shortest path' but it is often inacurate, you might need to construct the order yourself if it is a full loop edge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Obj = cmds.ls(sl=True, o=True)
Edges = cmds.ls(Obj[0]+'.e[*]', fl=True)
```

Here is a link for the orderedSelection flag and loop edges :
http://forums.cgsociety.org/t/return-selection-orderd-by-edge-loop-maya-api/1577329/6

Note that highliting ls and right clicking, you can open maya documentation about 'ls' and you have a quick that open a tab with all flags

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22412691)

Comment: I can link to maya documentation.... And say see the doc.... There is no code snippet, the question has many answers in this state

Comment: It would be preferable to just explain how it works along the lines of your comment on the question (about triggering the 'ordered selection'). You could include a link to the docs as well as that. Thanks for taking the time.